# Deep copying Java objects with circular references

Tags: java

How would I go about implementing a deep copy for `Foo`?  It contains an instance of `Bar`, which  then has a reference to that `Foo`.

```
public class Foo {

    Bar bar;

    Foo () {
        bar = new Bar(this);
    }

    Foo (Foo oldFoo) {
        bar = new Bar(oldFoo.bar);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Foo newFoo = new Foo(foo);
    }

    class Bar {
        Foo foo;

        Bar (Foo foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        Bar (Bar oldBar) {
            foo = newFoo(oldbar.Foo);
        }
    }
}
```

As it stands, this code would cause a stack overflow due to infinite recursion.

Also, this is the most simplistic example I could construct.  In practice, the object graph would be larger, with multiple instance variables which could themselves be collections.  Think multiple `Bar`s, with multiple `Foo`s, for instance.

---

**EDIT**: I'm currently in the process of implementing @chiastic-security's method.  Am I doing it correctly for Foo?  I'm using a separate HashMap to contain all parts of the object graph so that I can write the deep copy functionality as generally as possible.

```
Foo (Foo oldFoo) throws Exception {
    this(oldFoo, new IdentityHashMap<Object, Object>(), new IdentityHashSet<Object>());
}

Foo (Foo oldFoo, IdentityHashMap<Object, Object> clonedObjects, IdentityHashSet<Object> cloning) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Copying a Foo");

    HashMap<Object, Object> newToOldObjectGraph = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    newToOldObjectGraph.put(bar, oldFoo.bar);
    deepCopy(newToOldObjectGraph, clonedObjects, cloning);
}

void deepCopy(HashMap<Object, Object> newToOldObjectGraph, IdentityHashMap<Object, Object> clonedObjects, IdentityHashSet<Object> cloning) throws Exception {
    for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : newToOldObjectGraph.entrySet()) {
        Object newObj = entry.getKey();
        Object oldObj = entry.getValue();

        if (clonedObjects.containsKey(oldObj)) {
            newObj = clonedObjects.get(oldObj);
        }
        else if (cloning.contains(oldObj)){
            newObj = null;
        }
        else {
            cloning.add(oldObj);
            // Recursively deep clone
            newObj = newObj.getClass().getConstructor(oldObj.getClass(), clonedObjects.getClass(), cloning.getClass()).
                newInstance(oldObj, clonedObjects, cloning);

            clonedObjects.put(oldObj, newObj);
            cloning.remove(oldObj);
        }
        if (newObj == null && clonedObjects.containsKey(oldObj)) {
            newObj = clonedObjects.get(oldObj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, using any of your parameterized constructors would do this, so I think a redesign is in order.

Comment: If you didn't want to implement it yourself eventually, there are libraries which take care of that, e.g. Dozer: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: you have to pass the collections into the deep recursive clone methods.  also, using HashSet isn't safe because you could have objects which are equals() but not the same.

Comment: @jtahlborn is right. Good catch. You need an `IdentityHashSet`. I'll amend my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to implement a deep copy that might involve circular references, if you want it to be tolerant of changes to the structure later, would be to use an `IdentityHashMap` and an `IdentityHashSet` (from [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/util/IdentityHashSet.html)). When you want to copy:

1. Create an empty `IdentityHashMap<Object,Object>`, to map source objects to their clones.
2. Create an empty `IdentityHashSet<Object>` to track all the objects that are currently in the process of being cloned, but haven't yet finished.
3. Start the copy process going. At each stage, when you want to copy an object, look it up in your `IdentityHashMap` to see if you've already cloned that bit. If you have, return the copy that you find in the `IdentityHashMap`.
4. Check in the `IdentityHashSet` to see if you're in the middle of cloning the object you've now reached (because of a circular reference). If you have, just set it to `null` for now, and move on.
5. If you haven't previously cloned this (i.e., the source object isn't in the map), and you're not in the middle of cloning it (i.e., it's not in the set), add it to the `IdentityHashSet`, recursively deep clone it, and then when you've finished the recursive call, add the source/clone pair to the `IdentityHashMap`, and remove it from the `IdentityHashSet`.
6. Now at the end of your recursive cloning, you need to deal with the `null` references you left hanging because you encountered a circular reference. You can walk the graph of source and destination simultaneously. Whenever you find an object in the source graph, look it up in your `IdentityHashMap`, and find out what it should map to. If it exists in the `IdentityHashMap`, and if it's currently `null` in the destination graph, then you can set the destination reference to the clone you find in the `IdentityHashMap`.

This will make sure you don't clone the same part of the graph twice, but always end up with the same reference whenever there's an object that appears twice in your graph. It will also mean that circular references don't cause infinite recursion.

The point of using the `Identity` versions is that if two objects in your graph are the same as determined by `.equals()`, but different instances as determined by `==`, then a `HashSet` and `HashMap` would identify the two, and you'd end up joining things together that shouldn't be joined. The `Identity` versions will treat two instances as the same only if they're identical, i.e., the same as determined by `==`.

If you want to do all this but without having to implement it yourself, you could have a look at the [Java Deep Cloning Library](https://code.google.com/p/cloning/).

Comment: Why do we need to track objects which are in process of being copied? Once we've met them, their copies are legal to be referenced, hence HashSet is not needed.  IdentityHashMap would be safer.

Comment: @Basilevs Well, it depends on the API. If you have no-arg constructors for everything, then you're right, you just need the `HashMap`, because once you've got a reference, you're sorted. But if your instances are being created with constructors that need the objects they contain to be passed to them at creation time, then this won't work, and you need the `HashSet` too: you don't have a reference to the parent when you're creating the children. I was trying to give as general a solution as possible.

Comment: @Walker If you're living in a democracy, no one is going to force you to implement anything :)

Comment: @Walker I've edited the post and added a link to a project that will do it for you.

Comment: Is this something that would be used inside of each copy constructor, or is there some general place I would stuff the functionality?

Comment: Whoops, that sentence fragment earlier wasn't supposed to be a post, haha!

Comment: @Walker You'd need some code within each object that determined which bits needed deep cloning, i.e., helped you construct the object graph. But the library I linked to does it all via reflection, so it happens automatically without you needing to worry about the details. It's quite cool.

Comment: Is IdentityHashSet part of the standard library?

Comment: @Walker No, but I've given a link in the first paragraph.

Comment: Just updated my solution in the original question.  I think this is what @chiastic-security was getting it.  Would appreciate if someone could confirm I'm going down the right path!

Comment: @Walker Nice. I haven't checked the full details, but this certainly looks like it's going in the right direction. Actually if you have no-arg constructors for all your objects (as you seem to), you can simplify things a little and drop the `IdentityHashSet`. When you clone an object, and it's not one you've cloned before, the first step is to create a new instance and put it in your `IdentityHashMap`. Then you fill in the blanks in terms of the objects it references. That means that on your recursive step, anything you're cloning is guaranteed to be already in your `IdentityHashMap`.

Comment: @Walker Er, sorry, no, they don't all have no-arg constructors, but you could add them in if you wanted to.