# How to make deep Copy of an object, that has a reference of its type inside the object in java

Tags: java

How to make deep Copy of an object, that has a reference to its type inside the object in java

```
public class Employee implements Cloneable {
    private String Lastname;
    private String Firstname;
    private Employee supervisor;
    private Employee staff[];
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Employee copy = (Employee) super.clone();
        copy.supervisor = (Employee)supervisor.clone();
        copy.staff = staff.clone();
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything in your code except the copy of the array is fine.

Comment: [Avoid `Cloneable` and `clone()` whenever possible since it is broken by design](https://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html). Write a copy constructor instead. For a deep copy, you would have to copy the array manually by iterating through the array and copy the `Employee`s one-by-one.

Comment: @Turing85 Except to copy arrays. Though of course you won't get a deep copy like that.

Comment: @LouisWasserman What would happen if there's a cycle in employee graph?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @lexicore  the problem is I am trying to find an efficient way of cloning tree-like structure because in the question each employee can have a supervisor and that supervisor can have his own supervisor .....so on. The same with the staff, each staff can have his own employees which in turn they can have their own staff...and my solution is not working.

Comment: @merimemax Describe "not working".

Comment: Directed Tree-like structures (i.e. loop-free structures) are easy, you just have to copy the array(s) manually. Structures that allow loops, on the other hand, are not trivial, see @SeanVanGorder 's possible duplicate-link.

Comment: @lexicore by not working I mean the clone in my solution is not a deep clone because the cloned supervisor can have his own supervisor ...

Comment: @Turing85  where is the link you mentioned

Comment: @lexicore if think this is a duplicate question could you please forward me the link to the previous one.

Comment: @merimemax The [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191782/deep-copying-java-objects-with-circular-references) is linked.